# Methods best practice - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, methods

I have a program that is getting pretty big and it is a pain to find everything through all the functions and classes.

I am trying to break it up into other files based on their method.

Some of these functions have calls to others in the main class. I changed most my functions from private to public to access this. I had problems calling certain code created windows so importing mainwindow helped that.

My last problem is editing the mainwindow ui from one of the module files. I want to make sure im on the right page before i continue breaking it up. My only guess is that anything they updates the ui should be left on the main class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only code in your form class should be code that talks to other classes and updates the UI based on data from other classes.

Depending on your application, the form class might handle change events from other classes to update the UI or pass user input to other classes in `Change` or `Click` events.

Comment: Thanks, its just hard breaking it up as most of the functions update the ui directly. So will have to make more functions.

Comment: @Jasin: Consider exposing the UI properties (not objects) that they update in an interface implemented by the form.

Comment: Could you give me an example? For instance I have a datagrid. So one of the functions adds something to it after its calculationa and runs datagrid.items.Add(etc).  Edit - or keep it simple and just start with a label.

Comment: If you have a Status label that you update, you could make an interface with a `string Status { get; set; }` property, then implement that interface in the form to update the label.  You can then make the other classes take that interface (and pass the form itself) and set the property whenever you want.

Comment: Thank you sir, I understand now. Very nice.

Comment: No matter which solution you use, be careful about synchronizing access to data passed between the form and your logic modules (if you're using multiple threads).

Answer (score 1):

A couple options:

1. Use callbacks into the your main window.
2. Create events for when you need the form updated.  Your program logic raises the events, and your main window class can consume them.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I'm going to go with option 1. Don't think I need events for small UI updates.